# Will Grails GSP Safe Navigation Operator protect against "JSONObject$Null"?

Tags: json, grails, groovy, operators, gsp

In my Grails GSP I have the below code...

```
<div class="starshipStatus">${ship.engine.report?.substring(0,40)}... </div>
```

where the 'report' member can sometimes have an empty value. I am sometimes getting this exception on that page...

```
 org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: 
 Error executing tag <g:render>: 
 No such property: title for class: 
 org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject$Null
```

Could that exception be originating from that line or does the Safe Navigation Operator ('?') protect against "JSONObject$Null"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null safe operator `?` in Groovy will not help avoid this error because `NULL` is not the same as `JSONObject.NULL`. The latter is an actual object that represents the value of `NULL` and isn't actually `NULL`.

You can however do something like this:

```
<g:if test="${!ship.engine.report.equals(null)}">
...
</g:if>
```